# How to create custom dialog box with custom listview

Tags: android

Thanks for previous questions.

Is it possible to create a custom dialog box which includes custom listview which contains radio button. to be simple i want to create a dialog box which includes list view and radio button. i tried default listview inside the dialog box but the radio button is not indicating the item. How to give a default listview radio button that should always indicate the item. pls help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create custom dialog box with custom layout. For that,

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(**Your Context**);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.**Your Layout File**);
  dialog.show();
```

In this layout file you can make your layout as per your requirements.
When you want to use ListView from your Dialog Layout file then you have to write

```
  ListView listView = (ListView)**dialog**.findViewById(R.id.**Your ListView Id**);
```

If you can not understand then I'll give you Example.

I hope it helps you.. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks buddy. i got some idea from your answers, can you give me a example which brings me a more descriptive manner. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome HariRam, I gave you example code earlier if still you confuse then I will explain you deeply.. You can decalre your Dialog as globaly in your Activity. Then when you want to display that dialog then you can simply call dialog.show() method. But if you want to display list from that dialog then first you have to get Reference of list from that Dialog Layout. for that you have to use findViewById with dialog object.

Its very simple.


For more reference you can see http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a facility to create the custom dialog with custom layout. 
See the bellow links.It may help you.
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example